# Image picker ViewController app stuck - NSXPCConnection

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When I'm choosing image using image picker just after changing the permission settings for library in settings.

I'm getting an exception from OS. And the app is stuck. even didPickImageMedia delegate is not fired.

> ```
> 2018-05-07 11:08:04.413510+0530 PersonalCare[1369:75557] [general] <NSXPCConnection: 0x1c41153c0> connection from pid 1374: Warning:
> ```
>
> Exception caught during invocation of received message, dropping
>   incoming message and invalidating the connection.
>       Exception: *** -[NSURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil.
>       *** -[NSURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil.
>       (
>         0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018423bd50  + 148
>         1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000183750528 objc_exception_throw + 56
>         2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018423bc80  + 0
>         3   Foundation                          0x0000000184c4d91c  + 92
>         4   PhotosUI                            0x000000019707d4a0  + 1660
>         5   PhotosUI                            0x000000019707c92c  + 36
>         6   Foundation                          0x0000000184d501e0  + 20
>         7   Foundation                          0x0000000184d4e97c  + 2632
>         8   Foundation                          0x0000000184b25830  + 240
>         9   libxpc.dylib                        0x0000000183ea2300  + 68
>         10  libxpc.dylib                        0x0000000183e9fcb0  + 984
>         11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010371152c _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
>         12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103714f58 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 380
>         13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010371ff30 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 212
>         14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001037144c0 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 992
>         15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010371ff30 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 212
>         16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001037149a4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 332
>         17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103721104 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 424
>         18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103728100 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
>         19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000183e66fe0 _pthread_wqthread + 932
>         20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000183e66c30 start_wqthread + 4
>       )

My code

```
extension ProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            buttonImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let imageData: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.7)!
            encoded = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithCarriageReturn)
            profileImage = pickedImage
            buttonImage.setBackgroundImage(pickedImage, for: .normal)
        } else if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            buttonImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let imageData: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.7)!
            profileImage = pickedImage
            encoded = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithCarriageReturn)
            buttonImage.setBackgroundImage(pickedImage, for: .normal)
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code which you have used for choose and image from picker view?

Comment: i think error not in imagepicker error in using  base64EncodedString just check where you use it after pick image

Comment: Did you find any solution for same?

Answer (score 1):

Because many functions of UIImagePickerViewController will removed in future release(new version iOS14). You should using `PHPickerViewController`

```swift
import PhotosUI
 if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            // using PHPickerViewController
            var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: PHPhotoLibrary.shared())
            config.selectionLimit = 1
            config.filter = .images
            config.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
            let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
            picker.delegate = self
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            let imagePickerViewController = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePickerViewController.allowsEditing = false
            imagePickerViewController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            imagePickerViewController.delegate = self
            imagePickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            if(Device.isPad) {
                imagePickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
                imagePickerViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView  = self.view
                imagePickerViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.frame
                imagePickerViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

```swift
extension ViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    @available(iOS 14, *)
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard !results.isEmpty else { return }
        // request image urls
        let identifier = results.compactMap(\.assetIdentifier)
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: identifier, options: nil)
        var count = fetchResult.count
        fetchResult.enumerateObjects {(asset, index, stop) in
            PHAsset.getURL(ofPhotoWith: asset) {[weak self] (url) in
                if let url = url {
                  // got image url 
                } else {
                  // show error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
extension PHAsset {
static func getURL(ofPhotoWith mPhasset: PHAsset, completionHandler : @escaping ((_ responseURL : URL?) -> Void)) {
            if mPhasset.mediaType == .image {
                let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
                options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
                    return true
                }
                mPhasset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
                    if let fullSizeImageUrl = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL {
                        completionHandler(fullSizeImageUrl)
                    } else {
                        completionHandler(nil)
                    }
                })
            } else if mPhasset.mediaType == .video {
                let options: PHVideoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
                options.version = .original
                PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: mPhasset, options: options, resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) in
                    if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                        let localVideoUrl = urlAsset.url
                        completionHandler(localVideoUrl)
                    } else {
                        completionHandler(nil)
                    }
                })
            }
            
        }
}
```

Comment: Type 'PHAsset' has no member 'getURL'

Comment: @VladimirSukanica i updated `getURL` static function for PHAsset